# Proof of convergence of projected gradient descent via induction

Tags: optimization, induction, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

**Background**

I'm working through the "The constrained case" in section 3.2 of Bubeck's [Convex Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4980). The part I'm confused about is the proof of Theorem 3.7:

> Let $f$ be convex and $\beta$-smooth on $\mathcal X$. Then projected
>   gradient descent with $\eta = 1/\beta$
>   satisfies
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x_t) - f(x^\star) \leq \frac{3 \beta \|x_1 - x^\star\|^2 + f(x_1) - f(x^\star)}{t}
> \end{align*}

**The problem**

The proof makes sense to me up until the point where induction is used as follows. Define $\delta_s = f(x_s) - f(x^\star)$. It states

> ...the two above displays will imply \begin{align}
> \delta_{t+1} \leq \delta_t - \frac{\delta_{t+1}^2}{2\beta \| x_1 - x^\star\|^2}
> \end{align}
>   An easy induction shows that
>   \begin{align*}
> \delta_s \leq \frac{3 \beta \|x_1 - x^\star\|^2 + f(x_1) - f(x^\star)}{s}.
> \end{align*}

How is induction used to obtain this result? It is stated as if it is simple, but I'm having trouble seeing it.

**My attempt**

I tried starting with the base case $\delta_1 \leq \|x_1 - x^\star\|^2 + f(x_1) - f(x^\star)$, clearly. From here, I assume the result holds for all $k \leq s$. Then I tried,
\begin{align*}
\delta_{s + 1} \leq \frac{3 \beta \|x_1 - x^\star\|^2 + f(x_1) - f(x^\star)}{s} - \frac{\delta_{s+1}^2}{2\beta \| x_1 - x^\star\|^2}
\end{align*}
but I'm confused on how to deal with the other $\delta_{s+1}^2$ term. The algebraic manipulations I tried were unsuccessful.